# How to set the backgroud icon for a cordova ios app

Tags: ios, cordova

I have all the icons that Cordova sugests for ios in therir documentation, nevertheless, when I send tha app to background it shows a cordova icon:

[image: ios app in backwround mode]

Which icon or what configuration should I use show there my app's icon?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look inside : `ProjectDirectory/res/icon/`

If you're using Cordova for Android, so change all icons inside "`Android`"

Hope you got it !!

Comment: Thanks! Actually I did something like that at the beginning. I replaced every single "standard" icon and added those that weren't there (according to cordova's documentation). Since all the icons in "res/icon/ios" folder are my app's icons I don't know where is this backwround icon.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following site to generate my icons: https://pgicons.abiro.com/

Example config.xml : https://pgicons.abiro.com/config.xml

Comment: Thanks... I think I could have omitted some of the ones mentioned there. Thanks for the page recomendation.

Comment: No problem! Hope you are able to fix it.